# DOS at command scheduling

Tags: backup, scheduling, at

I wanted to make a schedule that runs a (backupping) .bat program using at command on startup. If it isn't possible, then at 5 PM sunday.

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What OS are you using? MS-DOS? PC-DOS? Windows 95? Windows XP?

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: I didn't try anything yet because I'm not use to using the at command, basically I want to know how to use it...

Comment: First, the "at" command will schedule a task, but you only need to run it once to set the schedule & task details.  Second, why don't you want to use the built-in Task Scheduler which provides a nice easy-to-use GUI.  Third, please try reading the help from typing "AT /?" or researching the command before posting.